# Cron expression for 24 hour period

Tags: cron

I'm trying to write a crontab expression that will begin a specified period of time and run on an interval for a 24 hour period.  For example I want the job to run every Thursday beginning at 4 PM and repeat every hour for 1 day.  Is there a way to do this? Everything I have tried stops at the end of the day Thursday.

Answer (score 1):

You need two crontab entries, one for the occurrences on Thursday and one for the occurrences on Friday.

For example (I have not tested this):

```
0 16-23 * * 4   your_command
0  0-15 * * 5   your_command
```

The fifth column is the day of the week, with Sunday=0. (Vixie cron also lets you specify the day of the week by name.)